# How to organize diamond-style project hierarchy in MSVS2010

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Imagine we have Visual Studio 2010 solution with project hierarchy as on the image:

[image: solution project hierarchy (example)]

In total 5 projects: 1 application, 4 static libs, that depend on each other as shown by arrows on the diagram.

In real solution that we have, there are:

- ~15 "top-level" applications/DLLs
- 4 "level 1" static libs (like A and B)
- ~30 "level 2" static libs (like C and D).

Each level-1 library depends on almost all level-2 libraries, and each application depends on 1 (rarely 2-3) level-1 static libraries.

The question is how to correctly set up **Framework and references** tab for MSVS2010 to build this configuration and to provide *easy* way to add new top-level applications.
*Easy* means that I don't want to manually add all level-2 libraries to each application. The best solution is to reference only level-1 libraries from applications, and reference level-2 libs only from level-1 libs.

I've already tried following approaches:

1. Simply reference all the libs from each application project. It works, but it's very difficult to maintain: for each application project (there can be up to 15 of them) you can have 30-35 references. It's nearly 500 references in total!
2. The most straightforward approach: from application projects reference level-1 libs, from level-1 libs reference level-2 libs.

Second approach can be used with different **Link Library Dependencies** and **Use Library Dependency Inputs** flags values (the per-reference ones, not the ones on a Linker/Librarian pages!).

1. In application project references page **Link Library Dependencies** is **TRUE** and **Use Library Dependency Inputs** is **FALSE** for all referenced level-1 libs. In library projects both of these are **FALSE** (the default value). Sometimes it works (especially when full solution rebuild is called), but from linker and librarian command lines (I see them in Project Properties), it's clear that it shouldn't work - nothing tells linker to link level-2 libraries. They are not packed into level-1 libs as well (I see that from **dumpbin** output). And it fails when I first press "Build" on level-1 libraries, and then try to "Build" the application.
2. The same as before, but in level-1 lib projects I set **Link Library Dependencies** to **TRUE** for each referenced level-2 lib. This tells librarian to include level-2 libs into level-1 libraries (this can be verified with **dumpbin**). And it fails when linking application, as each level-2 lib exists in several instances - one instance per level-1 lib.
3. The same as #1, but **Use Library Dependency Inputs** is **TRUE** in application projects for each referenced level-1 lib. Suddenly, with this settings, application linker now links all the object files from both level-1 and level-2 libraries throughout the hierarchy. This works well, but such behavior looks like some sort of magic and is not clear to me. Why it links level-2 libraries *.objs at all, when I reference only level-1 libs from application? And if it's correct behavior, then why it *doesn't* link level-2 libs in approach #1?

We're also using CMake on other platforms to build this project, and at least with Makefiles generator CMake handles such project hierarchy pretty well - it just links static libs from all hierarchy levels when linking application.